# Automate form request once a week?

Tags: forms

I am posting form data to a google spreadsheet through a regular old `<form action="<Google Sheet URL>" method="POST">`. Google doesn't allow for the form to be posted via AJAX, so I'm stuck to doing it this way. My input values are populated by JSON response data from various APIs. When the user submits the form, a video is automatically created using the data in the form.

After a video is created the first time, I need the data (in the inputs) to be updated once a week, and resubmitted. Instead of the user having to login, and hit submit again, how could I automate this for them?

Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="sheet" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1P6iosp_9AoYA1Rcn86T8j8_6xHdKp5KCKmEexMiDTsA/formResponse" target="hidden" method="POST">
    <div>Enter Filename</div>
    <input id="filename" type="text" name="entry.944320400">
    <div>Enter Name</div>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="entry.2146460057"><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm guessing this is going to take some PHP, since this will have to be server-side? But I'm just a little confused on where to start.

Comment: That depends entirely on your backend system. It can be done dozens of ways. Can you give us more information on your infrastructure?

Comment: Hi Ernest, thanks for the reply. Submitting the form, adds a new row to a google sheet with the data from the `<input>` fields. This row, is then automatically ingested into Adobe After Effects to start the video rendering process. I'm looking for a way to automate this process so a user doesn't have to manually hit "Submit" on the form after the initial video creation.